# Trying to have a table update based on user input in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to have it so that when a user selects a specimen range and species, the table will only show that range.

The code below creates the table and the inputs, but there appears to be no communication between the two. What am I missing?

## Load Libraries

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(glue)
library(plotly)
```

## Read Data

```
iris <- read_rds("iris.rds")

iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Flower dimensions by species"),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "species",
        label = "Select species",
        choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
      ),
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "specimen_selection",
        label = "Select specimen range",
        min = min(iris$id),
        max = max(iris$id),
        value = 50
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "Specimen_details")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Specimen_details <- renderDataTable(iris)
}
```

## Shiny App

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what iris$id is, but the problem was that `renderDataTable()` had no inputs to "listen" to, so the table was static.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Flower dimensions by species"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                inputId = "species",
                label = "Select species",
                choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                multiple = TRUE
            )
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput(outputId = "Specimen_details")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$Specimen_details <- renderDataTable({dplyr::filter(iris, Species %in% input$species)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I gave this a go, but the dplyr section didn't work. I receive this error:

    Error : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
    i Input `..1` is `species %in% input$species`.
    x Can't access reactive value 'species' outside of reactive consumer.
    i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?

Comment: What does your iris dataset looks like? It seems that it differs from built-in iris. You can use `dput(head(iris))` to ouput the structure.

Comment: dput(head(iris))
structure(list(id = 1:6, sepal_length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 
5, 5.4), sepal_width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9), petal_length = c(1.4, 
1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7), petal_width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.4), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Please, copy and paste my answer directly into R console, it should work. Notice that the code inside `renderDataTable` is wrapped with braces `{}`

Comment: I did so and it is still not working. I am receiving the following error:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5431
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `species %in% input$species`.
x object 'species' not found
  110: <Anonymous>

Comment: I get the same error if i put species in lowercase. `dplyr::filter(iris, Species %in% input$species)}` is not the same as dplyr::filter(iris, species %in% input$species)}

Comment: This is now working for me! The only problem is that it only allows me to sort based on a species, and does not display the id slider, do you know how I can incorporate both?